The equivalence of two definitions of relative interior?
I am reading this book.
Please allow me to first write down some definitions to make sure we are on the same page.
"When $X$ is a metric space"
Let $X$ be a metric space whose metric is $d$. For any $x \in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$, we define the $\varepsilon-$neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ as the set
\begin{equation*}
N_{\varepsilon, X}(x):=\{y \in X: d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}.
\end{equation*}
A subset $S$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ if, for each $x\in S$, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $N_{\varepsilon, X}(x) \subseteq S$.
Let $T \subseteq X$. The largest open set in $X$ that is contained in $T$ is called the interior of $T$ (relative to $X$) and is denoted by $int_X(T)$.
"When $X$ is a linear space"
Let $S$ be a subset of a linear space $X$. A vector $x$ in $S$ is called a relative interior point of $S$ if for any $y \in aff(S)$ [the affine hull of $S$], there exists an $\alpha_y>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
(1-\alpha)x+\alpha y\in S
\end{equation*} for all $0 \leq \alpha \leq \alpha_y$. The set of all relative interior points of $S$ is called the relative interior of $S$ and is denoted by $ri(S)$.
Exercise 21 on page 444 of this book is as follows.
Given any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $ri(S)=int_{aff(S)}(S)$ for any nonempty convex subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I am not asking how to prove it (even though I don't know). My question is, does the above statement hold only for convex sets? For example, let $S$ be two line segments on the same line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This set is not convex because there is a gap between the two segments. But both $ri(S)$ and $int_{aff(S)}(S)$ are the set of non-end points, and thus they are the same.
Edit: I should change my question to: are there any (non-convex) sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that this statement is false? Thank @Robert Israel for pointing this out.

Your example shows that it is not only for convex sets.  Perhaps you meant to ask whether there are (non-convex) sets for which it is not true.

For an example where the two are not the same,  let
$S$ be the complement of the curve $\{(x,x^2) \in \mathbb R^2: x > 0\}$.
The affine hull of $S$ is $\mathbb R^2$, and $(0,0)$ is in $ri(S)$, but it is not in $int_{\mathbb R^2}(S)$.

By definition, the premise of $y \in ri(S)$ is $y \in S$, but $(0,0)$ does not belong to the $S$ you proposed. Even if we add $(0,0)$ to $S$, I still don't see why it belongs to $ri(S)$.

Note that I said "complement", and $x > 0$.  So $(0,0)$ is not on the curve, and therefore is in its complement.  It is in $ri(S)$ because for any $(y_1, y_2) \in S$, $(1-\alpha) (0,0) + \alpha (y_1, y_2) = (\alpha y_1, \alpha y_2)$ is on the curve for at most one $\alpha > 0$, namely $y_2/y_1^2$ if $y_1, y_2 > 0$, and thus is in $S$ for all other $\alpha$.
